# how to use replace_regex_copy() from boost::algorithm library?

Tags: c++, boost

This is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/regex.hpp>
string f(const string& s) {
      using namespace boost::algorithm;
      return replace_regex_copy(s, "\\w", "?");
}
```

This is what compiler says:

```
no matching function for call to ‘replace_regex_copy(const
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char> >&, std::string, std::string)
```

The link to the library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/replace_regex_copy.html

Could anyone please help? Thanks!

ps. Boost library is in place, since other functions from it work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace_regex_copy` takes a `boost::regex` as its second argument, not a `std::string`.

There is an *explicit* conversion from `std::string` to `boost::regex`, but no implicit conversion exists, so you can fix your code by changing it to...

```
string f(const string& s) {
      using namespace boost::algorithm;
      return replace_regex_copy(s, boost::regex("\\w"), "?");
}
```